# Perl Program to search for a string over a set of files over SSH

Tags: perl, ssh

I have a perl script which can be used to ssh into a remote server using [`Net::SSH2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSH2), i need to search for a particular string over the files in a given directory in the remote system and print the given files in which the string occurs . Any ideas /sample codes  on how i can go about this ? 
Thanks

Comment: `ssh <user>@<host> grep -d recurse -l <string> <directories>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution proposed and accepted in the comments:

```
ssh <user>@<host> grep -d recurse -l <string> <directories>
```